# awk: how to include file names when concatenating files?

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

Am running `GNUwin32` under windows 7.

Have many files in a single directory with file names that look like this:

```
chem.001.txt
chem.002.b4.txt
chem.003.md6.txt
(more files.txt) ...
```

In their current form, none of the files includes the file name.

Need to clean these files for further use.
Want to concatenate all files into a single file.
But also need to include the file name at the beginning of concatenated content to later associate the original file with clean data.

For example, the single, concatenated file (new_file.txt) would look like this:

```
chem.001.txt delimiter (could be a tab or pipe) followed by text from chem.001.txt...
chem.002.b4.txt delimiter followed by text from chem.002.b4.txt ...
chem.003.md6.txt delimiter followed by text from chem.003.md6.txt ...
etc. ...
```

Will then clean the concatenated file and parse content as needed.

`awk` - `gawk` may have a means to associate the file name with ($1), associate the text in the file with ($2) and then, in sequence, print ($1, $2) for each file into 'new_file.txt' but I've not been able to make it work.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in foo.awk:

```
BEGIN{ RS="^$"; ORS=""; OFS="|" }
{ gsub(/\n[\r]?/," "); print FILENAME, $0 > "new_file.txt" }
```

and then execute it as

```
awk -f foo.awk <files>
```

where `<files>` is however you provide a list of file names in Windows. It uses GNU awk for multi-char RS to let you read a whole file as a single record.

Comment: I'm doing something wrong. I have the foo.awk and the .bat program in the directory with the target files. foo.awk directs output as follows:  BEGINFILE { print FILENAME > "C:\data\additives\new.txt" }
{ print > "C:\data\additives\new.txt" }. The foo.awk program reads data as follows: C:\bin\gnuwin32\bin\awk -f foo.awk *.txt. The one gotcha is that the data is on D: I've noticed before that I need to move the target data from D: to C: for awk to work correctly. Is there an error in my implementation of your code?

Comment: I moved data to C: Also check the version of awk. It is 3.1.6.2962

Comment: Have moved the 2 programs to their own directory (C:\data\additives_program). foo.awk looks like this: BEGIN{ RS="^$"; ORS=""; OFS="|" }
{ gsub(/\n[\r]?/," "); print FILENAME, $0 > "C:\data\additives\new.txt" } The .bat program looks like this: C:\bin\gnuwin32\bin\awk -f foo.awk C:\data\additives_combo\*.txt. Not yet getting a result. Is there a debugging step I should add to see what's failing?

Comment: I have 619 .txt files - none are empty.

Comment: Stackover is supressing a slash in my comments. the source directory is c:\data\additives_combo slash star.txt

Comment: What is the error you are experiencing? A core dump, a syntax error, incorrect output, no output or something else? The only thing that springs to mind is the use of backslashes instead of forward slashes in your directory path may be a problem. I don't use Windows so I don't know how gawk will know that a `\n` (as in your output file name `...\new.txt`) is intended to be literal. Maybe you need to write `C:\\data\\additives\\new.txt` or `C:/data/additives/new.txt`? Or move the output redirection outside of the script, e.g. `awk -f foo.awk file > "C:\data\additives\new.txt"` or whatever....

Comment: Just getting a quick flash of the DOS screen and then a return to windows. No file is created in the target director that might say, for instances, 0 output. Gimme a moment to think this thru. I have access to a linux server and may try it there. The awk will be the ubuntu awk. Will be back to you.

Comment: This is goofy. I put all artifacts into a single folder. In powershell I tested the access path to awk. I also tested the access path to the content folders. Using ls I tested that ls *.txt properly lists all files. When I run the .bat program in powershell it echos back - C:\bin\gnuwin\bin\awk -f foo.awk C:\data\additives_combo BACKSLASH STAR.txt - "The system cannot find the path specified." I'm gonna break and come back to this with a fresh perspective. I have some other Ed Morton awk programs that work and look to see what's different.

Comment: I put the awk program in the target folder and you programs work. One more addition to my Ed Morton file. TY.

Comment: My best advice - forget trying to run tools directly in Windows, just install cygwin and everything will behave sensibly.